# BCP Error "Unable to open BCP Format File"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bcp

I am trying to generate a new format file from a view in order to create a pipe-delimited flat file.

I am using `xp_cmdshell` in SSMS 2014

I am using this code:

```
BCP [UGM31EdwDemo].dbo.vwCCLF1_Output   format nul -c -f C:\CCLF1Demo.fmt -t, -T
```

This is the result I am receiving:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP
>   format file

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There could be other issues, but I provided an answer below that could be whats going on. One important note, you should avoid using XP_CMDSHELL. It introduces severe security risks when the command is allowed. It should be disabled on the SQL Server

Comment: What command would you recommend instead of XP_CMDSHELL?

Comment: This should be submitted as another question, but dont ask which one to use. Just ask, generically, what other options are there for a production enviroment/automation rather than to call BCP thru t-sql using xp_cmdshell. But there are other options. SSIS bcp thru the execute process task, t-sql "bulk insert" if you only need to load data and an SSIS data flow for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (because there are a few things that could be wrong) this is because the SQL Server service account cannot write the root C:\ folder. Try using a different path/network share.

When using XP_CMDSHELL, it's important to note that you are no longer the "user" executing the passed BCP command. When you pass your BCP command string to XP_CMDSHELL, a new session/thread is started on the underlying OS (outside of SQL Server processing). This new session uses the authentication of the account that the SQL Server is running as.

It is this other account that needs access to write to the location you are placing the format file.

Further, if your SQL Server is a networked SQL Server (not a SQL Server running on your desktop) it is most likely that permissions to write to C:\ have been blocked. Even a desktop may have been configured by an IT department to not allow writing to the C:\ root folder.

Just try writing to a different folder that you know has been given access to all to write to.